# MySQL query fails in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migrate

Using this query:

```
users = User.where('confirmed_at is NULL AND confirmation_sent_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? days)', 1)
```

In mysql goes okay but in Postgresql it fails with:

> ```
> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
>     LINE 1: ...AND confirmation_sent_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day))
>                                                                  ^
>     : SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
>       WHERE (confirmed_at is NULL AND confirmation_sent_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day))
> ```

I'm trying to understand but missing the context here. Why is the integer 1 not valid in this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function `DATE_SUB()` in PostgreSQL, so it cannot work.

This expression would work in Postgres:

```
... AND confirmation_sent_at <= (now() - interval '1 day')
```

Or, if `confirmation_sent_at` is a [`date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html):

```
... AND confirmation_sent_at <= (now()::date - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that DATE_SUB() could have be a mysql function only a bit cleaner than the one below

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
users = User.where(
    "confirmed_at IS NULL " +
    "AND confirmation_sent_at <= (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY')"
)
```